# AngularJS protractor test in nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have nested `ng-repeat` like this. I am the doing protractor test. So I want to access the first index of parent repeater.

```
   <div ng-repeat="pChild in mainParent | orderBy : 'order'" ng-show="checkfor.qm">
        <div  ng-repeat="cChild in Child ">
<input id="checkbox-01" type="checkbox" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-not-empty">
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, I want to select first child of `mainParent` and inside it,  I want to calculate length of Child.
I am new to protractor test. Please help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Shouldn't your inner loop be `ng-repeat="cChild in pChild | ......` , i.e. pChild instead of Child?

Comment: [Eureka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7549483/eureka), You are right. I have edited the question. Would you like to read again??

Comment: You mean you want first `pChild`? `element(by.repeater('pChild in mainParent').row(0))`. I don't understand length of child. You mean number of children inside this parent? Or is there only one child inside each parent.

Comment: [Fcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6485082/fcin)  yes, you understood right. Thanks for responding. But I got the answer, And I have mentioned it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var elm = element(by.repeater("pChild in mainParent").row(0)).all(by.repeater("cChild in Child")).map(function (elm) {
            return elm.element(by.css("input#checkbox-01")).getAttribute("class");
        }).then(function (links) {
            console.log(links.length);
          })
```

links.length have provided the length.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to calculate the length of `cChild` of first child of `mainParent`. You can use below code.

```
<div ng-repeat="pChild in mainParent| orderBy : 'order'" ng-show="checkfor.qm" ng-init="parentIndex = $index">
    <div ng-repeat="cChild in pChild| orderBy:'iseeit__Priority__c' ">
       <span ng-if="parentIndex === 0">cChild.length<span>
    </div>
</div>
```

instantiate the parent index with some local variable, and check if it's the first element.

Let me know, if you are looking for something else.

Comment: [Sachet Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4221611/sachet-gupta), I can't edit an angular script Because I don't have. Is there not any other way in protractor

Comment: Thanks for support [Sachet Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4221611/sachet-gupta) But I got the Answer..